# Conceptual Questions re debugging PHP web application in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging

I'd like to debug a web application written in PHP in Eclipse but I have two questions that I need to get answered before I can hope to proceed.

First, how do I choose between the Zend debugger and Xdebug? I have no idea what the difference between them is.

Second, I am not remotely clear on WHERE the debugging takes place. I can picture any of these approaches working:

1. The debugging takes place entirely within Eclipse.
2. The code runs in a local environment like XAMPP.
3. The code runs on a remote server.

Frankly, I'd prefer the first of those alternatives for sheer convenience and simplicity. Is that realistic? My second choice would be to test on the remote server but, given that it is space on a free hosting service, I can imagine that the hosting company might not let me install the various facilities that would be necessary for debugging to work.

Comment: [This](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug) might be a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you, Patrick, that was very helpful. It took a bit of fidgeting but I've got it launching XDebug successfully, for the first time ever. Initially, it was skipping lots of statements but I've sorted that out too now so I'm a happy camper. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome.  For future reference, this question isn't really a great fit for SO, at least as it is written.  It could probably be seen as both opinion-based ("how do I choose between the Zend debugger and Xdebug?") and as too broad (asking multiple questions).  You also don't indicate what work or research you'd already done to try to accomplish your goal.  That link I gave you was the very first result when Googling "php eclipse xdebug"